# which library I have to include in my eclipse to use Thread.sleep()

Tags: myeclipse

I want to use in my code : "Thread.sleep(10000);" in my esclipe

in netbeans it worked and I just included: 
"import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;"
so what should i do in myeclipse to use it

thank u

Comment: Thread is part of the java.lang package, so I don't think you need to import anything... What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Strange. How about using `import java.lang.Thread;`?

Comment: the  import java.lang.Thread; cannot be resolved :S

Comment: may be because I'm using BlueTools SDK II ??

Comment: PS this class worked normally in netBeans without any error
but when I copied it in BlueTools SDK II (myeclipse) it gives me a lot of errors.

Comment: If you look at Preferences > Java > Installed JREs, is the Java JDK installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make sure you handle any exceptions that could arise. Adding a try/catch statement will do the trick:

```
    try {
       Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was a beginner when i asked this question hehehe thanks for your answer :)